# Update em uma tabela com valores de outra

Tags: mysql, query, select

Como atualizar os valores de uma tabela, usando valores pegos em outra tabela:

```
UPDATE produto -- atualizar a tabela produto 
   SET produto.quant = SUM(entrada.quant) --  produto.quant será igual a soma da coluna quant da tabela entrada
 WHERE produto.id = entrada.idproduto -- onde produto.id = entrada.idproduto
```

Tabela produto:

```
id int
descricao string
tipo string
quant int
```

Tabela entrada

```
id int
idProduto int
data date
quant int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode setar o valor do `quant` do produto, com base em outra consulta, observe
como ficaria:

```
UPDATE produto
   SET produto.quant =
       (SELECT SUM(entrada.quant)
          FROM entrada
         WHERE produto.id = entrada.idproduto)
```

Fiz um exemplo no [SQLFinddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9d80f/1), caso queira verificar.

---

Fiz uma alteração, não consegui simular o problema relatado nos comentários, então fiz uma alteração:

```
UPDATE produto
   SET produto.quant =
       (SELECT SUM(IFNULL(entrada.quant,0))
          FROM entrada
         WHERE produto.id = entrada.idproduto);
```

Exemplo com a estrutura das suas tabelas no [SQLFinddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfd485).

Comment: deu erro 1048: Column 'quant' cannot be null

Comment: antes que pergunte. não tenho nenhum valor nulo na coluna quant de nenhuma das tabelas. o que pode ser?

Comment: Tens algum registro na tabela entrada ?

Comment: @Maurivan tem sim. David, alterado

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo, da uma olhada na alteração que fiz.

Comment: @David ainda deu o mesmo erro :/

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas decidi fazer o código pelo próprio aplicativo ao invés de fazer pela query.